# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs

Just trying to render a list of items obtained from my backend but getting this error indicating it's undefined.  However, when I check the console log I can see that the component's state definitely has 5 items in the array.

```
class PubSubTopics extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pubsubtopics: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callBackEndAPI()
            .then(res =>
                this.setState({pubsubtopics: res.express}))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
        console.log('after setting state');
        console.log(this.state.pubsubtopics);
    }


    callBackEndAPI = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/listtopics');
        const body = await response.json();

        if(response.status !== 200){
            throw Error(body.message)
        }
        console.log('after API responded');
        console.log(body.topics);
        return body.topics;
    }
    render(){
        const list = [];
        for(const[index, value] of this.state.pubsubtopics){
            list.push(<li key={index}>{value}</li>)
        }
        return(
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {list}
                </ul>
                <button onDoubleClick={this.handleClick}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Console log:

```
after setting state
index.js:21 (3) ["one", "two", "three"]
index.js:32 after API responded
index.js:33 (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Any idea why it's saying `this.state.pubsubtopics` is undefined?

Comment: "After setting state" is logged before the `callBackEndAPI` function finishes and sets the state. Can you copy/paste the entire error message you're getting?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
PubSubTopics.render
src/index.js:38
  35 | }
  36 | render(){
  37 |     const list = [];
> 38 |     const pubsubtopics = this.state.pubsubtopics.slice();
     | ^  39 |     for(const[index, value] of pubsubtopics.entries()){
  40 |         list.push(<li key={index}>{value}</li>)
  41 |     }

Comment: Was able to getting it working after realizing the backend's array was nested in a key:
                this.setState({pubsubtopics: res.express.topics}))

Answer (score 40):

check all the brackets used in the code at the specified line number. example -

In my case this was throwing an error -

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState['']
```

When I corrected this,

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
```

This was working fine for me.

Please check if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 11):

If you have recently updated your MacOS and if this error shows up suddenly, it must be because MacOS Monterey is not listed in the list of OS.

Add this line to the top of index.js and then this error will be fixed.

```
const nameMap = new Map([
    [21, ['Monterey','12']],
    [20, ['Big Sur', '11']],
    [19, ['Catalina', '10.15']],
    [18, ['Mojave', '10.14']],
    [17, ['High Sierra', '10.13']],
    [16, ['Sierra', '10.12']],
    [15, ['El Capitan', '10.11']],
    [14, ['Yosemite', '10.10']],
    [13, ['Mavericks', '10.9']],
    [12, ['Mountain Lion', '10.8']],
    [11, ['Lion', '10.7']],
    [10, ['Snow Leopard', '10.6']],
    [9, ['Leopard', '10.5']],
    [8, ['Tiger', '10.4']],
    [7, ['Panther', '10.3']],
    [6, ['Jaguar', '10.2']],
    [5, ['Puma', '10.1']]
]);
```

Comment: Can anyone explain how this answer is related to the question and how is this OS related? :P

Comment: I'm beyond puzzled at how this answer got so many upvotes lol

Comment: node modules > insight > macos > index.js
Change this file and everything gonna works fine again

Comment: This libraty "insight" receive updates, but did not update the name list of SO macs. The same way with the library "macos_release"

Comment: @m4n0 Because you get the same error when you update Mac OS. It is true that the answer is not very related to the question, but it is a LIFE SAVER! Upvote :)

Comment: If you recently have upgraded to ventura then you should prepend `[22, ['Ventura', '13.1']],` into the above map.

Comment: If you've recently upgraded to Sonoma then you shoul- you should- you, you should prepend `[23, ['Sonoma', '14']],` into the- the above map!!

Answer (score 8):

You can't destruct in a `for..of` iteration over an array, because what you're trying to iterate isn't destructible. You're essentially trying to do this on each iteration

```js
const [index, value] = this.state.pubsubtopics[0]
// this is equivalent to const [index, value] = "one", for example.
```

What you want to do is use `this.state.pubsubtopics.entries()`, which returns an array of key-value pairs. Here's an example:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b'];
// arr.entries() is [[0, 'a'], [1, 'b']]
for (const [index, element] of arr.entries()) {
    // const [index, element] = [0, 'a'] on 1st iteration, then [1, 'b'], etc. 
    console.log(index, element);
}
```

Comment: I had added .entries() to this.state.pubsubtopics but it's still complaining that "Cannot read property 'entries' of undefined".  Seems like the state is getting cleared out somewhere.

Comment: Was able to getting it working after realizing the backend's array was nested in a key:
                this.setState({pubsubtopics: res.express.topics}))

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the error was happening simply because the array I was iterating over had `undefined` as it's value.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was using array destructure syntax where as the return output is an object when using the useQuery hook.

wrong:

const [data,error,loading] = useQuery(GET_LOCATIONS);

Right:

const {data,error,loading} = useQuery(GET_LOCATIONS);

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using **useEffect** in place of **useState**.

Wrong:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useEffect(false);
```

Right:

```
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, this shouldn't work:

```js
for(const [index, value] of ['one', 'two', 'three']) {
  console.log({index, value}); //this displays {index: "o", value: "n"}
}
```

It looks like you want to use the `index` value for the `key` which you can get from using the `map` array function.

```
return(
  <div>
    <ul>
      {(this.state.pubsubtopics || []).map((value, index) => (
        <li key={index}>{value}</li>
      )}
    </ul>
    <button onDoubleClick={this.handleClick}/>
  </div>
);
```

I'm not sure why `this.state.pubsubtopics` would be undefined though, but perhaps it won't be when it's fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was enclosing an object within an object:

```
  <AppContext.Provider value={{loggedIn, setLoggedIn}}>
```

The issue was fixed when I used an array within the object:

```
  <AppContext.Provider value={[loggedIn, setLoggedIn]}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the array mapping. Be sure you are iterating it right. When using Virtual Table same error appears if you not make extensions as columns are. In short Order matter

Answer (score -19):

Add this line of code and the end of index.js

```js
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Then make sure you import it or if it's commented, uncomment the import code and it will work.

Comment: Answers like this don't really serve to help anyone learn